# Div with position fixed inside another div

Tags: css, position, fixed

I'm trying to fit a div with position: fixed inside another div and next to another one

```
<div class="container">

 <div class="fixeddiv"></div>
 <div class="contentdiv"></div>

</div>
```

My container div have a width of 1300px and should be in the middle of the paeg (margin auto)
The fixed div should be on the left side inside the container but shouldn't move when scrolling to read the bottom of the content div

I have try around with position: fixed but it always ends up on the left side and not in the middle of the page.

To illustrate what i had like i have make this picture:
[image]

Can i have suggestions how i can make this work please. My thougths are going away from position fixed and try to solve it with javascript but i had like to do it without js.

Comment: You can achieve that but it will still move whenever the patent DIV moves

Comment: your fixed div is pretty thin, so there is a lot of unused space in container. You need to get margin-left for your fixed div with appropriate value. If you want for example 10px between two divs then (1300-180-10)=110 margin-left:110px;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want the `fixed` `div` to take full height set `top:0` `bottom:0` and `overflow-y:scroll` if you want to make it scroll
- for the content `div` just set `margin-left` little more then the `fixed` `div` so that it leaves some space

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.fixeddiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.contentdiv {
  margin: 0 0 0 120px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fixeddiv">
    <h1>fixed div</h1>

    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="contentdiv">
    <h1>width auto content</h1>

    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
    <p>Sed mollis, eros et ultrices tempus, mauris ipsum aliquam libero, non adipiscing dolor urna a orci. Nullam tincidunt adipiscing enim. Nunc interdum lacus sit amet orci. In ac felis quis tortor malesuada pretium.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and your effort. Both answers given will work for me. I'm gonna try both out and see what in the long term works the best.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then try something like this.

Applying `position: fixed` takes the DIV out of the normal flow of the document and the right column will end up stacking below the left (fixed) column. You can float the right column to the right to fix this or you could add an appropriate margin to the left side of the right column.

*HTML*

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        Left
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right
    </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left,
.right {
    color: white;
}
.left {
    background-color: blue;
    min-height: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 50px;
}
.right {
    background-color: red;
    float: right; /* or replace float with: margin-left: 100px */
    min-height: 1000px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

In the fiddles below I modified the container and column widths to better illustrate inside jsFiddle.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvawqtfh/ - float version

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uvawqtfh/1/ - margin-left version

Comment: Thank you for this solution and your effort. Both answers given will work for me. I'm gonna try both out and see what in the long term works the best.